# Set different color to one side of mirrored object

Tags: modeling, mirror, mirror-modifier

i'm modeling a police car and using the mirror modifier. I want to change some of the police lights on one side of the car only, how may i achieve this? Any help would be much appreciated!

[image: Image of the car i'm modeling]

UPDATE:  My intention is to turn red the blue lights to the left side of the car, can i achieve this?

UPDATE 2: FYI I set the lights on the main object to red. Afterwards I had to duplicate the blue lights with Shift + D, then P to separate by selection, then changed the colors of the selection to blue and turned off the mirror modifier!

Comment: Probably best to select the lights and use 'P' to seperate them by selection, then go back into Object mode and apply the mirror modifier to them. You can then modify them individually without affecting the rest of the model.

Comment: My intention is to turn red the blue lights to the left side of the car, can i achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your lights and the body of the car are all one object, this is an approximation of your object:
[image]
In edit mode, select your lights then press <kbd>P</kbd> and <kbd>Separate</kbd> from the menu:
[image]
Go back into Object mode and select the lights which are new a new object. Apply the Mirror modifier.
[image]
You can now apply different colours to the lights on each side of the car, but the Mirror Modifier will still be avalable on the main object:
[image]

Comment: Thanks, have to tweak it a little bit but finally worked!

FYI I set the object lights to red. Afterwards I had to duplicate the blue lights with Shift + D, then P to separate by selection, then changed the colors of the selection to blue and turned off the mirror modifier!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I thought that this thing is probably impossible to do and it would probably be better to apply modifier and change material of those 2 later, but I have found a solution:
[image]

This is just my try, it may not be the best solution, there can be a better solution and someone may give you an easier and better answer but you can do it this way as well.